# FFmpeg でエラー: No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg

以前FFmpegを使って動画を編集していましたが、本業が忙しく一年近く触っていませんでした。
本日久々に編集しようとしたら、どのコマンドを実行してもと赤文字で出ます。

```
（ファイル名）.mp4: No such file or directory
```

勿論、該当ファイルはffmpeg.exeと同じ階層（フォルダ）に置いてあります。

パスを通しなおしてみたり、一度ffmpeg自体を削除して入れなおしてみたりもしたのですが、ダメでした。
更にコマンドプロンプトを立ち上げて最初にffmpegに移動した際、version等の情報が表示された後、以下のような黄色い文字のメッセージも出ます。
以前はこんなのなかったような気がします。

```
Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

解決方法が分かる方おられましたら助けてください。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: OSは何でしょうか？ ffmpegのバージョンは何でしょうか？

Comment: "Use -h to get full help" 、そのまま「使い方は `ffmpeg -h` で確認してください」といったメッセージであり、警告等ではありません。(以前のバージョンではオレンジ色でこのメッセージが表示されていたようです。) No such file or directory、つまりファイルが見当たらないということなので指定しているファイル名が正しいか確認してみてください。また、引数が誤っていませんか？

Comment: ひとまず、実行したコマンドをオプションや指定したファイル名も含めて質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: 通常、ファイルを「ffmpeg.exeと同じ階層（フォルダ）」に置く必要はありません。
そこらへんで何か勘違いが有るかも知れません。
ファイルの指定方法の理解は十分ですか？
例えば、「フルパス」「相対パス」「カレントディレクトリ」などの概念は理解されていますか？
もし忘れてしまっているようであれば、再度確認してみて下さい。

Comment: ご意見ありがとうございます。
まずはバージョンについてです。

エディション：Windows 10 Pro
バージョン：21H2
ffmpeg version N-108306-ge7a987d7c9-20220923 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: 以下がコマンドプロンプトで実行した結果です。（長くて送り切れないので分割しています）

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2006]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USER>ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe
ffmpeg version N-108306-ge7a987d7c9-20220923 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.55_3defb7b)

Comment: configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpuls

Comment: enjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220923

Comment: libavutil      57. 36.102 / 57. 36.102
  libavcodec     59. 44.101 / 59. 44.101
  libavformat    59. 32.101 / 59. 32.101
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 49.100 /  8. 49.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

Comment: C:\Users\USER>ffmpeg -i ptm.mp4 ptm.mp3
ffmpeg version N-108306-ge7a987d7c9-20220923 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.55_3defb7b)

Comment: configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype

Comment: --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r

Comment: --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt

Comment: --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220923

Comment: libavutil      57. 36.102 / 57. 36.102
  libavcodec     59. 44.101 / 59. 44.101
  libavformat    59. 32.101 / 59. 32.101
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 49.100 /  8. 49.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
ptm.mp4: No such file or directory

Comment: 本来はmp4を圧縮（20GBくらいあるので4.7GBにしたい）して、VOBにしてテレビのDVDプレイヤーで見れるようにしたいのです。
しかしうまくいかないので、まずはmp4をmp3に変換してみようとしました。
ptm.mp4というファイルをffmpeg.exeと同じ階層においてます。
同じ階層においてる理由は絶対パスをミスしないようにする為で深い意味はありません。

Comment: 「フルパス」「相対パス」「カレントディレクトリ」などの概念は理解しているつもりなのですが…何か根本的に抜けている気もしてきました。おさらいしてきます。

Comment: ffmpegを置いている場所も書いておきますね。C:\Users\USER\ffmpeg